# Can I set disabled the "New Folder" button of filedialog.askdirectory() tkinter's widget?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tk-toolkit

When I place the Dialog Box of the Tkinter package (module named filedialog) for choose a directory from a treeview with the askdirectory() widget, in Windows and Mac OSX (not in Linux), there is a button for create a New Folder.

I want to disable this button, because in some situations it's very dangerous.

I've read [tkdocs.com](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/windows.html) and [Tkinter 8.5 reference: a GUI for Python](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/index.html) but I didn't found anything about this.

Comment: On my Win7 machine, there's no 'New Folder' button on the `askdirectory()` widget (but it's there on all others).

Comment: There is no option to disable that button. You will have to create your own dialog.

Comment: You can set `mustexist=True` which will remove that button under macOS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to alter the built-in dialog widgets. These are provided by the operating system, not tkinter.